# Как заблюрить только элемент div, не изменяя остальное?

Tags: html, css

Итак, у меня сверху есть div в котором лого и тд, нужно заблюрить только цветной блок, не затрагивая остального, можно ли это сделать?
[image: как выглядит div]

Comment: что такое цветной блок? не оч понятно

Comment: Под цветным блоком, я имею ввиду, что надо заблюрить только черный блок на изображении

Comment: в css есть filter: blur() https://webref.ru/css/value/blur

Comment: Когда я его использую, у меня блюрится сразу всё - и текст, и лого, нужно чтобы они не блюрились

Comment: на хедере сделайте фон `transparent`, под него закиньте абсолютом черный блок и его блюрте